# A calculus questionn

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let the function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$. We know that $f$ has following properties

i) The slope of its tangent at any point is equal to the ratio of the abscissa of that point cubed to its ordinate.

ii) The range of $f$ is the interval $[3,\infty]$.

What is the value of $f(14^{1/4})$?

My attempt is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^3}{y}$, then $y=f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^4}{2}+C}$. How can we use second hint to find constant $C$?

Comment: Note that $f$ is defined for all real $x$. Hence, $C\geq 0$. So, $f$ attains its minimum for $x=0$.

Comment: @trancelocation So $C$ is 9 and the answer is 4. Am i right?

Comment: So it is. :-) ... you are right.